# For Statement Not working C#

Tags: c#, loops

Creating a simple form which has 4 textboxes. Two are used for input and two are used for output. The user provides input for textbox 1 and 2, and the duplicate is replicated in the 3rd and 4th textbox. Now, when the button is clicked and a user inputs a second amount in text 1, I want the added total in text3.

```
 public void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int BayOne;
        int BayTwo;
        int BayOneTotal;
        int BayTwoTotal;
        BayOne = Convert.ToInt32(txtBayOne.Text);
        BayTwo = Convert.ToInt32(txtBayTwo.Text);

        for (int i = BayOne; i < 25000; i++)
        {
            BayOneTotal = i + i;
        }
        txtBayOneTotal.Text= BayOne.ToString();
        txtBayTwoTotal.Text= BayTwo.ToString();
    }
```

Inputs are in BayOne(Result dupcliated in BayOneTotal)..etc. The result is not adding properly. It just reduplicates the value posted the second time.

Comment: where is the infinite loop?

Comment: Very unclear. Post exact values for expected vs actual.\

Comment: I'm sorry. A For Statement, not a LOOP.

Comment: @user3874210 For statement is a loop, but not infinitive in your example

Comment: Yeah, `for` loops has been C#'s achilles heel since the start...

Comment: The values of `BayOne` and `BayTwo` are never changed.  That's why they show the same value.

Comment: Forget about code, what are you trying to do in English words? Which values are input, what do you expect as output and why?

Answer (score 5):

You're putting back `BayOne`, not `BayOneTotal`, into the text box:

```
// Should set the total
// txtBayOneTotal.Text= BayOne.ToString();
txtBayOneTotal.Text = BayOneTotal.ToString();
```

On a side note, a couple of things about this question:

1. You may want to consider using `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`. This will allow you to handle "bad" input more easily.
2. You may also want to consider using normal [C# naming and style guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx).  This would be `bayOne` instead of `BayOne`, etc.

Comment: But BayOneTotal is replicated from BayOne. A user inputs "1" in Bay one. I would hit submit and 1 would show in BayOneTotal. The second time a user enters 2, so the output in BayOneTotal after clicked would be 3.

Comment: @user3874210 That's a different issue, then.  You'd need to load it's value from the UI, and add to it, not just set it.

Comment: @Sean: _It just reduplicates the value posted the second time_ is worth a downvote or two. The OP still hasn't cleared that up.

Comment: @Henk: I was just noticing that the votes are not always very logical: If a question is stupid then its answer can't be very intelligent.